# "Early return" best practice and DRY

Tags: php, dry

I'm wondering is there a better way of "braking out" of method under some conditions. Let me better explain this with code:

```
function execute($context)
{
    // some init actions

    $event = new BeforeOperationOne();
    $this->dispatch($event);
    if ($event->accessGranted()) {
        $context->setUser($this->user);
        // other repeated code

        return;
    }

    $result = $this->operationOne();

    // some other code

    $event = new BeforeOperationTwo();
    $this->dispatch($event);
    if ($event->accessGranted()) {
        $context->setUser($this->user);
        // other repeated code

        return;
    }

    // this is not important what is access checker, 
    // this is just to show that all following code uses data
    // computed in previous steps
    $accessChecker = new AccessChecker($result);
    $this->operationTwo(accessChecker);

    // some other code

    $event = new BeforeOperationThree();
    $this->dispatch($event);
    if ($event->accessGranted()) {
        $context->setUser($this->user);
        // other repeated code

        return;
    }

    $this->operationThree();

    // some other code
}
```

We have repeated here the condition, setting user in context when user has access from event. What options I can think about is:

1. The ugly do-while(false) or goto (I better leave it this way as it is now)
2. Extract this to method and change the condition to `if (!$this->handleEvent($event, $context)) { return; }`- This doesn't help to much and cannot think a better name handle doesn't say it's returning something
3. Build array of closures for operations and loop it through checking. We can assume that all event classes are derived from common class with accessGranted methods. This can be ugly as some operations need data from previous "steps", I would have to keep them outside and pass them.
4. Throw and catch exceptions that user has access - another bad solution.

Do you have any ideas how to write it better?

Comment: Your question will receive a lot of opinion-based answers. But, take a look at [Object Calisthenics](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/), [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) and  Clean Code book - chapter 3 - Functions.

Comment: At last, the correct term is "[early return](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)"

Comment: Maybe "chain of responsibility" pattern will be useful?

Comment: What I'm trying to actually do is give possibility to hook into the method using event system and if it's possible to finish method earlier to avoid unnecessary heavy computing for user access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Greg i was thinking about something like that:

```
abstract class Handler
{
    protected $nextHandler = null;

    abstract public function Request($request);

    public function setNextHandler(Handler $handler)
    {
        $this->nextHandler = $handler;
    }

    protected function someOperations($event)
    {
        //i copied this section, so you must shape that
        $this->dispatch($event);
        if ($event->accessGranted()) {
            $context->setUser($this->user);
            // other repeated code

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class BeforeOperationOneHandler extends Handler
{
    public function Request($request)
    {
          if ($this->someOperations(new BeforeOperationOne())) {
              return;
          }

          $result = $this->operationOne(); // shape this too

          return $this->nextHandler->Request($result);
    }
}

class BeforeOperationTwoHandler extends Handler
{
    public function Request($request)
    {
          if ($this->someOperations(new BeforeOperationTwo())) {
              return;
          }

          $accessChecker = new AccessChecker($result); // shape this too
          $result = $this->operationTwo(accessChecker);

          return $this->nextHandler->Request($result);
    }
}

class BeforeOperationThreeHandler extends Handler
{
    public function Request($request)
    {
          if ($this->someOperations(new BeforeOperationThree())) {
              return;
          }

          $result = $this->operationThree(); // shape this too

          return $this->nextHandler->Request($result);
    }
}

class DefaultHandler extends Handler
{
    public function Request($request)
    {
          // this is the last step
    }
}




function execute($context)
{
    // some init actions
    $beforeOperationOneHandler = new BeforeOperationOneHandler();
    $beforeOperationTwoHandler = new BeforeOperationTwoHandler();
    $beforeOperationThreeHandler = new BeforeOperationThreeHandler();
    $defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler();

    // set the sequence of the elements
    // BeforeOperationOneHandler > BeforeOperationTwoHandler > BeforeOperationThreeHandler> DefaultHandler
    $beforeOperationOneHandler->setNextHandler($beforeOperationTwoHandler);
    $beforeOperationTwoHandler->setNextHandler($beforeOperationThreeHandler);
    $beforeOperationThreeHandler->setNextHandler($defaultHandler);

    return $beforeOperationOneHandler->Request($some_init);
}
```

It's only quickly written shape of "chain of responsibility" pattern so i thoughtlessly copied some of your code fragments
I hope this will lead you to a better solution

Comment: Thanks for clarify. This made me to rethink the solution. I'll go this way.